# How do I get two divs to stick to each other?

Tags: html, css

I have the following block of CSS/HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{CODE} Pink</title>
        <style>
            .leftLogo {
                float: left;
                border: black solid;
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
                font-family: Courier, Courier New;
            }


            .rightLogo {
                float: right;
                border: black dashed;
                background: pink;
                color: black;
            }
            .logo
            {
                height: 50px;
                line-height: 50px;
                width: 200px;

                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                font-size: 3em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="leftlogo logo">{CODE}</div>
        <div class="rightlogo logo">PINK</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What it's currently doing is this:

[image]

What I'd like it to do is this:

[image]

I know I can do this with positions, but what's the best way to do this so the two will stay next to each other in a variety of scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code for the `.rightlogo` `class` to reflect this:

```
.rightLogo {
    float: left;
}
```

instead of what it is currently:

```
.rightLogo {
    float: right;
}
```

**Note:** Also, be mindful of your capitalization of the classes. I noticed that in your `CSS`, you use `.leftLogo` but in your `HTML`, you use `.leftlogo`. I'm not sure how deep the browser requirements go for being that strict, but I wouldn't put it past IE to mess something up.

**The result:**

```css
.leftLogo {
    float: left;
    border: black solid;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Courier, Courier New;
}


.rightLogo {
    float: left;
    border: black dashed;
    background: pink;
    color: black;
}

.logo
{
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftLogo logo">{CODE}</div>
<div class="rightLogo logo">PINK</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, hadn't caught that one. Correcting now!

Comment: @Codingo To display a snippet, just click on the icon to the right of the insert image icon in the WYSIWYG editor, or press CTRL+M. A pop-up will appear that is reminiscent of JSFiddle. (I saw your question before you deleted it -_-)

Comment: Thanks :) I ended up figuring it out in the end by editing your question, but certainly didn't know about ctrl+M. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Codingo Np, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by adding `float: left;` to your *.logo* class and removing the *float* property inside *.leftLogo & .rightLogo*

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach for this question is to set the two logos(divs) inside a container, to have an absolute position so they overlap and then the one you want in the right give it a right of 100%.

```
html code
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftLogo logo">{CODE}</div>
  <div class="rightLogo logo">PINK</div>
</div>

css Code
.container{
  position: absolute;           
}
.rightLogo {
  right: 100%;
}
```

I have only put the code that needs to be add to what you currently have.**Good Luck**

**Hope this answer your Question** T04435...

PS:The divs in the original post have miss spell in the class names the ***l*** should be Capital ***L*** leftlogo ---> leftLogo and same for right

Comment: Appreciated! And I agree, making the change now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float:left` for right div, and resize width with media queries for resolution where second div go to bottom.

Comment: This is the answer but looks like RhapX beat you to it!